# Find dll being accessed by RegOpenKey in Process Monitor

Tags: dll, monitoring

I'm trying to find out which dll file is causing my problems.  I'm using Process Monitor.  It lists the Operation RegOpenKey and an error "NAME NOT FOUND" for the result, but doesn't tell me what that name is.  I looked at the column names I could add to the display, but none of them seemed like they would show me the name.

How do I determine the name of the file that RegOpenKey is working on?

Comment: You can attach the process to [Rohits API Monitor](www.rohitab.com/apimonitor) and capture calls to RegOpenKey.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value of `Path` is what is not found.
[image]

Comment: Yeh, this does let me know what key is being accessed, though I still don't know up front what dll is being called.  Thanks.